# Android - Why my app picks values on default folder (instead XXHDPI)

Tags: android, directory, drawable, multiscreen, screen-density

I try to test my app on a Samsung A34 (1080x2340):390 ppi. I expected that in this configuration the folders (drawable, mipmap, dimens...) would be XXHDPI, but the app takes values from Default folder.

Where is my mistake ?

I put some trace at the beginning of my app:

E/Résolution : {1080,2340}

E/Densité (float) : 2.46875

E/Densité (int)  : 390

E/True Densité : DEFAULT - 390

Thank you

Comment: What did you name your folder? xxhdpi?
Make sure you name your folders according to the google convention.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Comment: Hello my folder names are OK : drawable-xxhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, values-xxhdpi... and the sames for mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi....